Evaluate integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)+x}{x^2}~dx$
Evaluate : $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)+x}{x^2}~dx$$
I had the idea of using convergence, split it in  two integrals, but I can't end it.

Welcome to MathSE! Please see how to ask a good question. It’s better to show your attempt in the post. What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

I want to compute it

what do you mean by "using convergence"?

The antiderivative can be explicitly calculated, then just take the limits at the endpoints (because the integral is improper).

I got that by ibp :
$\int(\frac{log(1 - x) + x}{x^2} dx = \frac{((x - 1) log(1 - x))}{x} + C$
but I'm struggling to find the value at $x=0$ and $x=1$...

@PicsDeb edit the post

$$\int\frac{x+\log(1-x)}{x^2}\text {d}x=-\frac{x+\log(x)}{x}-\int\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-1}{x}\text {d}x$$
This was by using integration by parts.
$$\int\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-1}{x} \text {d}x=\int\frac{1}{1 - x}\text {d}x=-\log(1 - x)$$ and so
$$\int\frac{x+\log(1-x)}{x^2}\text {d}x=\log(1-x)-\frac{x+\log(1-x)}{x}+C\\=\log(1-x)-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}+C$$
Then we need to compute it from $0$ to $1$
When $x\to1$ , $\log(1-x)-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\to 0$
when $ x\to 0 , \log(1-x)-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\to 1$
So $$=\left[\log(1-x)-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x} \right]^1_0=0-1=-1$$

You can integrate by parts without proving the integral is convergent ?

Certainly! Also notice I did not use ibb on the original , definite, integral. I first solved the integral and then calculated it between the bounds given.

@PicsDeb . Also , IBB is a "way" , technique if you will of finding the antiderivative of a function. Solving an indefinite integral is exactly that. Here we had $f(x)=\frac{x+\log(1-x)}{x^2}$ and we found a function $g$ s.t $g'(x)=f(x)$.Definite integrals are just $y_2-y_1$ of the function $g$ where $y_2,y_1$ are the values of $g$ when $x$ is/tends to a certain value.

For fun we render a power series evaluation.
$\dfrac{\ln(1-x)+x}{x^2}=-\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-2}}{n}$
$\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln(1-x)+x}{x^2}dx=-\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-2}}{n}dx=-\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\int_0^1\dfrac{x^{n-2}}{n}dx$
(The series converges absolutely throughout the interior of the interval.)
$=-\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac1{n(n-1)},$
which gives $-1$ by a familiar telescoping.
